# Easyadmin 3 - How to render embedded form?

Tags: php, symfony, embed, easyadmin

I am trying EasyAdmin, and I am completely lost.
I have entity A which contains a relationship with entity B (which contains multiple fields).

In Entity A's CrudController, if I want to display fields from the relation (so, Entity B), how am I supposed to go about it?

In my current case I have a Portfolio entity that has a relationship with UserDetails (and which contains several fields that I therefore want to display in the form of the Portfolio entity)
I created a FormType for my UserDetails class, as we normally would. And in my CRUD controller, for the Portfolio entity, I put this:

```php
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            IdField::new('id'),
                        FormField::addPanel()->setProperty('userDetails')->setFormType(ProjectUserDetailsType::class)

        ];
    }
```

Is this the right way to go? Will the fields contained in this FormField be mapped correctly?

On the other hand when rendering, this "subform" is centered, unlike the others.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to embed a single object or form you could follow [this doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html)
If you want also embed a collection of objects [there is a way](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) for that using what is called prototypes.

For rendering the form and styles you could render each part separately and adding the proper styles on twig files or inside the form definition.

```
#rendering with twig
{{ form_label(form.field, 'label', { 'attr': {'class': 'foo'} }) }}
{{ form_widget(form.field, { 'attr': {'class': 'bar'} }) }}

#rendering inside html tags
<div class="form-control">
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{ form_label(form.dueDate) }}
{{ form_widget(form.dueDate) }}

<small>{{ form_help(form.dueDate) }}</small>

<div class="form-error">
    {{ form_errors(form.dueDate) }}
</div>
```